# Three tables with two arrows in one enviroment

Tags: tables, witharrows

I have these tree tables which I am trying to have them in one environment conncetd by arrows :

```
    \begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{StudentID} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Course} & Grade                  & P        \\ \hline
1              & Math      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{A} & $p_1= 0.25$ \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                &                             & B                      & $p_2=0.75$    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Probabilistic Database}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{StudentID} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Course} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Grade}        \\ \hline
1                               & Math                        & A                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{World 1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{StudentID} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Course} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Grade}        \\ \hline
1                               & Math                        & B                          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{World 2}
\end{table}
```

**Edit** The required output is as follows should fit in two column  :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Three tables with the captions "Probabilistic database," "World 1," and "World 2." The tables are positioned as described in the answer.]

The [Ti*k*Z package](https://tikz.dev/tutorial) is a popular package for illustrations in LaTeX, and with it, you can place text in *nodes* at points on a coordinate system. In the code below, I've positioned the "Probabilistic database" table so that it is always to the left of the origin (that is, the origin is to the `east`). I've positioned the "World 1" and "World 2" tables so that they are always to the right of (2,2) and (2,−2), respectively (that is, these anchor points are always to the `west`). Using `\draw[->]`, I've drawn arrows starting almost but not quite from the origin, and ending at the anchor points of the "World 1" and "World 2" table. You can change these coordinates to change how high or low the tables appear or where each arrow starts or ends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node [anchor=east,align=center,yshift=-1ex] {
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{StudentID} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Course} & Grade & P \\ \hline
      1 & Math      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{A} & $p_1= 0.25$ \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &           & B                      & $p_2=0.75$  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\[1ex]
    Probabilistic database
  };
  \draw[thick,->] (0.2,0.2) -- (2,2) node[anchor=west,align=center,yshift=-1ex] {
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{StudentID} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Course} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Grade} \\ \hline
      1                               & Math                        & A                          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\[1ex]
    World 1
  };
  \draw[thick,->] (0.2,-0.2) -- (2,-2) node[anchor=west,align=center,yshift=-1ex] {
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{StudentID} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Course} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Grade} \\ \hline
      1                               & Math                        & B                          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\[1ex]
    World 2
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My document is two columns how can I edit the code provided to fit ?

Comment: You can surround the entire Ti*k*Z picture with `\begin{figure*}[tb]`...`\end{figure*}` to create a figure that spans both columns.

Comment: Yeah that worked thanks a lot